# value of $a,b,c,d,e$ in expansion of determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If $\displaystyle \begin{vmatrix}x^2+3x & x-1 & x+3 \\ x+1 & -2x & x-4 \\ x-3 & x+4 & 3x\end{vmatrix}=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$

> Then $a,b,c,d,e$ equals

I have tried several times using transformation properties of determinant but I could not get any satisfactory way

So here I have  expand along  $(1)$ st Row

$\displaystyle (x^2+3x)\bigg[(-2x)(3x)-(x^2-16)\bigg]-(x-1)\bigg[(3x)(x+1)-(x-4)(x-3)\bigg]+(x+3)\bigg[(x+1)(x+4)+(2x)(x-3)\bigg]$

$\displaystyle (x^2+3x)(16-7x^2)-(x-1)(2x^2+10x-12)+(x+3)(3x^2-x+4)$

$\displaystyle -7x^4-20x^3+36x^2+27x+24$

After comparing, we get

$a=-7,b=-20,c=36,d=27,e=24$

How can  We expand the above determinant using transformation properties of determinant , please explain me, Thanks

Comment: Use the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus#:~:text=Rule%20of%20Sarrus%3A%20The%20determinant,along%20the%20up%2Dright%20diagonals.). The result is $-7x^4-20x^3+16x^2+71x$. This is different from your result. You can test it with $x=0$. Then the matrix has determinant zero. So $e=0$.

Comment: At the very last step you made a simple sign error. You added the middle term instead of subtracting it.

Comment: What "transformation properties" of determinant did you try and are referring to? Why did you "not get any satisfactory way"? Please include this information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an error in the step from

> $(x^2+3x)(16-7x^2)-(x-1)(2x^2+10x-12)+(x+3)(3x^2-x+4)$

to

> $-7x^4-20x^3+36x^2+27x+24$

---

Although this answer does not use transformation properties of determinant, this answer shows some observations which should make the calculations easier.

**Some observations** :

- $a_{11}=x(x+3),a_{22}=-2x,a_{33}=3x$ are divisible by $x$.
- $a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}=(x\color{red}{-1})(x\color{red}{-4})(x\color{red}{-3})$
- $a_{21}a_{32}a_{13}=(x\color{red}{+1})(x\color{red}{+4})(x\color{red}{+3})$
- Since $(x\pm a)(x\pm b)(x\pm c)=x^3\pm(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x\pm abc$, we see that $$a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{21}a_{32}a_{13}=2x^3+2(1\cdot 4+4\cdot 3+3\cdot 1)x=x(2x^2+38)$$ is divisible by $x$.

By the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus), the determinant is given by
$$\begin{align}&\underbrace{a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{21}a_{32}a_{13}}_{\text{divisible by $x$}}+\underbrace{\color{red}{a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}}-\color{red}{a_{22}}a_{13}a_{31}-\color{red}{a_{33}}a_{12}a_{21}-\color{red}{a_{11}}a_{23}a_{32}}_{\text{divisible by $x$}}
\\\\&=x\bigg(2x^2+38+(x+3)\times (-2x)\times 3x-(-2)(x+3)(x-3)-3(x+1)(x-1)
\\&\qquad\qquad-(x+3)(x+4)(x-4)\bigg)
\\\\&=x\bigg(2x^2+38-6x^2(x+3)+2(x^2-9)-3(x^2-1)-(x+3)(x^2-16)\bigg)
\\\\&=x\bigg((-6-1)x^3+(2-18+2-3-3)x^2+16x+38-18+3+48\bigg)
\\\\&=x(-7x^3-20x^2+16x+71)
\\\\&=-7x^4-20x^3+16x^2+71x\end{align}$$

Therefore, the answer is
$$\color{red}{a=-7,\quad b=-20,\quad c=16,\quad d=71,\quad e=0}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can decompose the determinant by the first column:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x^2+3x & x-1 & x+3\\
x+1 & -2x & x-4\\
x-3 & x+4 & 3x
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$=(x^2+3x)\begin{vmatrix}
-2x & x-4\\
x+4 & 3x
\end{vmatrix}
-(x+1)\begin{vmatrix}
 x-1 & x+3\\
 x+4 & 3x
\end{vmatrix}
+(x-3)\begin{vmatrix}
 x-1 & x+3\\
 -2x & x-4\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
$$=(x^2+3x)(-7x^2+16)-(x+1)(2x^2-10x-12)+(x-3)(3x^2+x+4)$$
$$=-7x^4+(-21-2+3)x^3+(16-2+10-9+1)x^2+(48+10+12+4-3)x+12-12$$
$$=-7x^4-20x^3+16x^2+71x.$$
Also, we can use the Sarrus' rule:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x^2+3x\color{brown}{_{\LARGE_\searrow}}\hspace{-20mu} & x-1\color{brown}{_{\LARGE_\searrow}} & x+3\color{brown}{_{\LARGE_\searrow}} & x^2+3x & x-1\\
x+1 & -2x\color{green}{^{\LARGE_\nearrow}}\hspace{-16mu}\color{brown}{_{\LARGE_\searrow}}\hspace{-16mu} & x-4\color{green}{^{\LARGE_\nearrow}}\hspace{-16mu}\color{brown}{_{\LARGE_\searrow}} &x+1\color{green}{^{\LARGE_\nearrow}}\hspace{-16mu}\color{brown}{_{\LARGE_\searrow}}\hspace{-20mu} & -2x\\
x-3\color{green}{^{\LARGE_\nearrow}} & x+4\color{green}{^{\LARGE_\nearrow}}\hspace{-20mu} & 3x\color{green}{^{\LARGE_\nearrow}}\hspace{-20mu} & x-3 & x+4
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$(x^2+3x)(-2x)\cdot 3x +(x-1)(x-4)(x-3)+(x+3)(x+1)(x+4)$$
$$-(x-3)(-2x)(x+3)-(x+4)(x-4)(x^2+3x)-3x\cdot(x+1)(x-1)$$
$$=-6x^2(x^2+3x)+2(x^3+(1\cdot4+4\cdot3+3\cdot1)x)$$
$$+2x(x^2-9)-(x^2+3x)(x^2-16)-3x(x^2-1)$$
$$=-6x^3(x+3)+2(x^3+19x)$$
$$+2x(x^2-9)-(x^2+3x)(x^2-16)+3x(1-x^2)$$
$$=(-6-1)x^4+(-18+2+2-3-3)x^3+16x^2+(38-18+48+3)x$$
$$=-7x^4-20x^3+16x^2-71x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet an other way to go, the first step is using the linearity of the determinant w.r.t. the first line, which is $(x^2+3x,x-1,x+3)=(x^2+3x, x,x)+(0,-1,3)$. The determinant $\Delta$ to be computed is thus $\Delta =\Delta_1+\Delta_2$ where
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta_1 &=
\begin{vmatrix}
x^2+3x & x & x\\
x+1 & -2x & x-4\\
x-3 & x+4 & 3x
\end{vmatrix}
=
x
\begin{vmatrix}
x+3 & 1 & 1\\
x+1 & -2x & x-4\\
x-3 & x+4 & 3x
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=x(x+3)
\begin{vmatrix}
 -2x & x-4\\
 x+4 & 3x
\end{vmatrix}
- x
\begin{vmatrix}
x+1 &  x-4\\
x-3 &  3x
\end{vmatrix}
+x
\begin{vmatrix}
x+1 & -2x \\
x-3 & x+4 
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=x(x+3)(-7x^2+16)-x(2x^2+10x-12)+x(3x^2-x+4)
\\
&=-x(7x^3 + 20x^2 - 5x - 64)\ ,
\\[3mm]
\Delta_2 &=
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & \boxed{-1} & +3\\
x+1 & -2x & x-4\\
x-3 & x+4 & 3x
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0\\
x+1 & * & -5x-4\\
x-3 & * & 6x+12
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
x+1 & -5x-4\\
x-3 & 6x+12
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
x+1 & -5x-4\\
-4 & 11x+16
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
x+1 & 1\\
-4 & 11x-4
\end{vmatrix}
=11x^2+7x=x(11x+7)\ ,\text{ so}
\\[3mm]
\Delta&=\Delta_1+\Delta_2=-x\Big(\ (7x^3 + 20x^2 - 5x - 64)-(11x+7)\ \Big)
\\
&=-x(7x^3 + 20x^2 - 16x - 71)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The needed coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ can now be easily extracted, they are respectively
$$\bbox[yellow]{-7\ , \ -20\ ,\ 16\ ,\ 71\ , \ 0\ .}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$ \text{det} = \begin{vmatrix}x^2+3x & x-1 & x+3 \\ x+1 & -2x & x-4 \\ x-3 & x+4 & 3x\end{vmatrix}=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e, $$

expand along  the first row to get

$$ \text{det} = (x^2+3x)\bigg[(-2x)(3x)-(x^2-16)\bigg] \\
  -(x-1)\bigg[(3x)(x+1)-(x-4)(x-3)\bigg] \\
  +(x+3)\bigg[(x+1)(x+4)+(2x)(x-3)\bigg].$$

Expand the bracketed terms to get

$$ \text{det} = (x^2+3x)(16-7x^2) -(x-1)(2x^2+10x-12)+(x+3)(3x^2-x+4) .$$

Multiply out each term to get

$$ \text{det} = (-7 x^4-21 x^3+16 x^2+48 x) - (2 x^3+8 x^2-22 x+12 ) + (3 x^3+8 x^2+x+12 ). $$

Combine the polynomial terms together to get

$$ \text{det} = -7 x^4-20 x^3+16 x^2+71 x. $$

Hence,

$a=-7,b=-20,c=16,d=71,e=0.$

There are other ways to calculate a $3\times 3$ determinant
but this seems to be the easiest to work with.